# Is there a way to compare one list contents in another list in same order?

Tags: java, collections

I'm automating an eCommerce website where i have to test whether sizes present in dropdown of a particular product are displayed in ascending order.

I declared contents list which holds the ascending order of size

```
public static final List<String> T_SHIRT_SIZE_LIST = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("Small (S)", "Medium (M)", "Large (L)", "X-Large (XL)", "XX-Large (XXL)"));
```

Now I've taken and store all the product size value in a list i.e.

```
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("Small (S)", "Medium (M)", "Large (L)","XX-Large (XXL)");
```

I want to compare the list2 contents should be in same order as `T_SHIRT_SIZE_LIST` has, even though some value missing in list2.

Comment: Are these values constant?

Comment: Yes these values in list1 are constant and in same order

Comment: what is your desired outcome after comparison. This question needs more specification, just saying that you want to compare does not mean anything. what is your **expected output**??

Comment: I have to test whether all the product size are in ascending order in e commerce website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you can instead do is use the Comparator/Comparable interface(s) to sort your list. You don't have to compare the two lists, just compare the elements in the list.

Edited to ensure you can convert from String to TShirtSize using a factory method.

```
enum TShirtSize {    
    SMALL(0, "Small (S)"),
    MEDIUM(1, "Medium (M)"),
    LARGE(2, "Large (L)"),
    XL(3, "X-Large (XL)"),
    XXL(4, "XX-Large (XXL)");

    private final int order;

    private final String identifier;

    TShirtSize(int order, String identifier) {
        this.order = order;
        this.identifier = identifier;
     }

    public static TShirtSize valueOfId(String id) {
            // cache use of values() in an immutable map/set
        return Stream.of(values()).filter(size -> size.identifier.equals(id)).findAny().orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
    }

    public String getIdentifier() {
        return identifier;
    }

    public int getOrder() {
        return order;
    }
}
```

```java
public static boolean isOrdered(List<TShirtSize> sizes) {
    List<TShirtSize> sizesOrdered = sizes.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(TShirtSize::getOrder)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return IntStream.range(0, sizes.size()).allMatch(index -> sizes.get(index) == sizesOrdered.get(index));
}
```

```java
List<String> actualSize = Arrays.asList("Small (S)", "Large (L)", "X-Large (XL)");
List<TShirtSize> actualSizeList = actualSize.stream().map(TShirtSize::valueOfId).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println("is expected : " + isOrdered(actualSizeList));
```

Comment: *what you can instead..* instead of what?? , BTW i like the use of `enum` here.

Comment: Haha instead of comparing the two lists against each other. Yeah me too, I think it's fitting use of enumerations.

Comment: With the use of `enum`, you don't really need to add the `order`/`getOrder` to sort it though. `enum` already implements `Comparable`, so you can just do `sizes.stream().sorted()`.

Comment: @daniu Yeah that is a perfectly valid point, the only problem is that it relies on Enum#ordinal which depends on the order that you define the elements in the enum. This makes it quite dangerous so instead we explicitly define order as to reduce confusion.

Comment: Okay, updated. You can convert from List of String to List of TShirtSize. You can also compare two lists.

Comment: Yeah, it's false because the first list contains 2 elements and the second list contains 5 elements. The first list should contain all 5 or the second should only contain the expected 2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206857/discussion-between-narendrar-and-jason).

Comment: @Jason That makes little sense. You define the order of the elements within the `enum` just as you do the ordering field, so both are equally explicit. The advantage of using the actual (`ordinal`-based) ordering within the file is that if you want to change it, you just move the elements around. Having an additional field means you have to adjust those as well, which is more work and error prone.

Answer (score 1):

You could just work with a mapping of the indexes:

```
public static boolean isInOrder(List<String> input) {
    List<Integer> indexes = input.stream()
        .map(T_SHIRT_SIZE_LIST::indexOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Integer> sorted = new ArrayList<>(indexes);
    Collections.sort(sorted);
    return sorted.equals(indexes);
}
```

(Input validation strategy would depend on your context)

Answer (score 0):

I think using `Guava` `Ordering` you could just do:

```
private static final Ordering T_SHIRT_SIZE_ORDERING = Ordering.explicit(T_SHIRT_SIZE_LIST);

...

T_SHIRT_SIZE_ORDERING.isOrdered(input);
```

However the caveat is that it will blow if `input` has any value that's not in your `T_SHIRT_SIZE_LIST`. That could be easily mitigated with an up-front check (and assuming `T_SHIRT_SIZE_SET` was an ordered set equivalent to `T_SHIRT_SIZE_LIST`):

```
return T_SHIRT_SIZE_SET.containsAll(input) && T_SHIRT_SIZE_ORDERING.isOrdered(input);
```

Also side note: if you're using Java 9+, save yourself some typing with `List.of`:

```
public static final List<String> T_SHIRT_SIZE_LIST = List.of("Small (S)", "Medium (M)", "Large (L)", "X-Large (XL)", "XX-Large (XXL)");
```